# How to change volume of a specific application using pipewire?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, gnome

I wanted to control volume of specific apps through media control buttons rather than the master volume. Solutions online mention pulseaudio but since my distro comes packaged with pipewire I haven't been able to piece anything together.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Pulsemixer lets you adjust volume per app:

```
apt install pulsemixer
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what you mean by been able to control volume of specific application through media control because each application has it shortcut or mapping for controlling volume .eg mpv you use 0 to increase 9 to decrease. But to generally control pipewire volume using the media keys **(on sway for example)**
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/WirePlumber#Tips_and_tricks

```
#To raise the volume
bindsym XF86AudioRaiseVolume exec wpctl set-volume @DEFAULT_AUDIO_SINK@ 1%+
#To lower the volume
bindsym XF86AudioLowerVolume exec wpctl set-volume @DEFAULT_AUDIO_SINK@ 1%-
#To mute/unmute the volume
bindsym XF86AudioMute exec wpctl set-mute @DEFAULT_AUDIO_SINK@ toggle
#To mute/unmute the microphone
bindsym XF86AudioMicMute exec wpctl set-mute @DEFAULT_AUDIO_SOURCE@ toggle
```

Or use pw-cli **(but it is more complicated,.eg you can't toggle mute easily or increase volume with a number relative to the current volume)**
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/wikis/Migrate-PulseAudio#sinksource-port-volumemuteport-latency
This is the command I use on my machine, reading the above docs tells you how you find the *index* and *device* values

```
pw-cli s 42 Route '{ index : 2, device: 8, props: { mute: false, channelVolumes: [ 2, 2 ] }, save: true }'
```

so you create a mapping to bind the media keys to this command